# Cannot add external libraries with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to add external libraries to my project in PyCharm using the

PyCharm > Preferences... > Project Interpreter > Python Interpreters -> Cog on the upper right hand side -> Click on + icon in Project Interpreters dialog

In the resulting screen, I add paths to the external libraries that I'd like to include in the project, and they get added to the list of paths in that dialog, but when I then expand the External Libraries entry in the Project window, the paths that I added are not shown.

I tried going through the contents of the .idea folder to identify where exactly the references to External Libraries are kept using .idea folder of a colleague but couldn't figure out the related settings file.

How can I get External Libraries added to PhCharm in this case?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: No, I am not using virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm > Preferences... > Project Interpreter > Python Interpreters -> Cog on the upper right hand side ->

1. Click on green color icon(use condova package Manager)
2. Click the + Add button to install any package. Its work for me